# Detecting storyboard from the crash log

Tags: ios, xcode, uistoryboard

I've a crash with the following log:

```
Storyboard (<UIStoryboard: 0x7ebdd20>) doesn't contain a view controller with identifier 'personDetailVC'
```

I've implemented code to switch storyboards based on some conditions and updates the storyboard name and view controller name accordingly. My required storyboard has the storyboard id `'personDetailVC'`. But I would like to verify if the storyboard is the correct one. Is there any way to track the storyboard from `<UIStoryboard: 0x7ebdd20>` information available from the log?

Comment: How did you access your storyboard when you tried to open the view?

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue because it was pointing to a wrong storyboard. I'm just curious to know if we can track storyboard from the log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to see the UIStoryboard description with gdb, into the log output write this:

```
po 0x7ebdd20
```

It's similar to a `NSLog("%@", yourObject)`.

`po` is the acronymous of print object, a special command of the gdb debugger to print the description of an object.